# Difference between min sdk > target sdk > target compiler in creating an android application

Tags: compiler-construction, sdk, kernel

1st: What is the difference between `min sdk > target sdk >` and `target sdk` compiler in creating an android application and comparing to compiler compliance level?

2nd: does target sdk ex. 4.2 matter with the android device for example `4.0.3 (Ice Cream Sandwich)` that I am using for development?

3rd: Using the code below created using android 4.2 as new project. I was notified with permgen space. I had 512M.. why?

here is the code

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, DriveScopes.DRIVE);
    startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getExtras() != null) {
        String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        if (accountName != null) {
          credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
          service = getDriveService(credential);
          startCameraIntent();
        }
      }
      break;
    case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        saveFileToDrive();
      } else {
        startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
      }
      break;
    case CAPTURE_IMAGE:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        saveFileToDrive();
      }
    }
  }

  private void startCameraIntent() {
    String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date());
    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(mediaStorageDir + java.io.File.separator + "IMG_"
        + timeStamp + ".jpg"));

    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
  }

  private void saveFileToDrive() {
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          // File's binary content
          java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());
          FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent("image/jpeg", fileContent);

          // File's metadata.
          File body = new File();
          body.setTitle(fileContent.getName());
          body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");

          File file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute();
          if (file != null) {
            showToast("Photo uploaded: " + file.getTitle());
            startCameraIntent();
          }
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
          startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
    t.start();
  }

  private Drive getDriveService(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
    return new Drive.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new GsonFactory(), credential)
        .build();
  }

  public void showToast(final String toast) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The part of the question relating to API Levels is covered pretty comprehensively in this API Guide in the Android documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

I don't understand what you are asking in the 3rd part of your question, and it should probably be posted as a separate question anyway.